# Controlling a TextBox's scroll position from the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is there a solution that involves a WPF TextBox/Block that auto scrolls to the end via binding?  This can obviously be done in the code behind by calling the control directly, but how would one do this with Binding and MVVM?

in the code behind that works (but I'd like to avoid that and use the VM to do everything)

```
  public void _readerService_BytesArrived(string s)
  {
     Action dispatcherAction = () =>
     {
        txtBoxOutPut.AppendText(s);
        txtBoxOutPut.ScrollToEnd();
     };
     Dispatcher.Invoke(dispatcherAction);
  }
```

Comment: What is wrong with doing it in code behind? It won't be against MVVM

Comment: While it's a pure UI concern and many people don't mind putting it in the code behind there are lots of people that still want to keep the code behind as empty as possible, where possible. 

Many times keeping things out of the code behind allows for unit testing and that can be a very important part of an application

Comment: @Erick: There are more types of tests than just unit testing. This would be a perfect situation to run a Coded UI Test, or just have QA actually visually look for this in regression testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An System.Windows.Interactivity Behavior may do just the trick for you. I use them for scrolling various controls and it's not in the VM but it's also not in the View and follows MVVM.

Below is an example for a Scrollviewer that may be helpful

```
    public class FrameworkElementScrollviewerScrollingBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    private FrameworkElement _AssociatedElement;

    private ScrollViewer _listboxScrollViewer = null;

    #region OnAttached
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        _AssociatedElement = AssociatedObject;
        _AssociatedElement.Loaded += OnControlLoaded;
        _AssociatedElement.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(_AssociatedElement_Unloaded);

        //TODO: register/subscrive for event/message from the VM that tells you the scrollviewer to do something
    }

    //TODO: handle the event using the _AssociatedElement as the control you are acting on

    void _AssociatedElement_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Cleanup();
    }
    #endregion

    #region OnDetaching
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        Cleanup();
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
    #endregion

    private bool _isCleanedUp;
    private void Cleanup()
    {
        if (!_isCleanedUp)
        {
            _AssociatedElement.Loaded -= OnControlLoaded;
            _AssociatedElement.Unloaded -= _AssociatedElement_Unloaded;
        }
    }


    #region OnControlLoaded
    private void OnControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            _listboxScrollViewer = GetDescendantByType(sender as Visual, typeof(ScrollViewer)) as ScrollViewer;

            if (_listboxScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
                //do something when content is scrollable
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region GetDescendantByType
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the descendent of type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Visual GetDescendantByType(Visual element, Type type)
    {
        if (element == null) return null;

        if (element.GetType() == type) return element;
        Visual foundElement = null;
        if (element is FrameworkElement)
            (element as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
            foundElement = GetDescendantByType(visual, type);
            if (foundElement != null)
                break;
        }
        return foundElement;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking that you're attempting to scroll to the end when the value of the Text changes inside of a TextBox/Block. Since this is a view-related operation, it should stay that way. Simply place a TextChanged event on the control and scroll to the end when the Text property changes.

---

Note that this basically means you need to split your operation... keep the binding on the view-model end, and place the ScrollToEnd in code-behind in your view... the view-model shouldn't care who is consuming the text string and how they behave.